# How can I reference a parameter from inside a parameterized stepList in Azure Devops Yaml Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

This is the `parameters` part of my template used from other templates/pipelines:

```yaml
    parameters:  
    - name: artifactName
      displayName: Name of the app artifact published to the pipeline
      type: string
```

Parameter `preBuildSteps` does not exist currently, I am trying to make a parameter of type `stepList` with a default value. This helps me introduce the ability to have pre-build step list as parameter but at the same time avoid breaking changes for all pipelines/templates using this template currently. And the displayed below is where I want to get to.

```yaml
    parameters:  
    - name: artifactName
      displayName: Name of the app artifact published to the pipeline
      type: string  
    - name: preBuildSteps
      displayName: 'Pre-Build Steps'
      type: stepList
      default:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download app artifact
        inputs:
          artifact: '${{parameters.artifactName}}'
          path:  '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
```

The problem is `artifact: '${{parameters.artifactName}}'` as I am trying to reference a parameter from inside a parameterized step list. The error I get trying to run the pipeline using the template is `A template expression is not allowed in this context`.

I have tried without single quotes `${{parameters.artifactName}}` and I have tried with braces like this `$(parameters.artifactName)`. I have also tried to create a variable assigning its value from the parameter `artifactName` and then reference that variable in the parameterized section to no avail.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Nick not the way I wanted as described in the post.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this directly, but you could work around it, by doing the following:

1. In the job where you wish to use the stepList parameter, add

```yaml
variables:
- artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}
```

before the steps in that job (where you would expand out your `preBuildSteps` parameter value)

2. In the stepList parameter default, reference that job-local variable:

```yaml
      default:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        displayName: Download app artifact
        inputs:
          artifact: '$(artifact)'
          path:  '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
```

It's conceivable you could also use `${{ variables.artifactName }}` in that reference as well, which would expand out the value at compile time - just not 100% sure the reference would be expanded at that point. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried this and it didn't work. I mention it in the post but it is probably not clear enough. The error I get trying to run the pipeline is `Unexpected value 'variables'`